# Graphite nginx requests per second

Tags: nginx, graphite

Is there any way how to get Graphite to graph req/s ?

When you retrieve nginx requests from nginx_status you are sending an absolute value to the graphite, so I'm thinking if there is any way how you can get the rate per second ?

My understanding is that `derivative(series)` would give you requests/minute but I could really use requests/s.

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this but it seems like this did the trick

```
scaleToSeconds(derivative(stats.*.*.*.nginx.handles),1)
```

Anyone sees any problems with this ?

Answer (score 2):

Run your nginx access logs through Logster, which will munge the data and forward several interesting metrics -- including requests per second, if you wish -- to Graphite.

https://github.com/etsy/logster